# Where is the error in this limit double integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I  have to find what happen in  this integral

\begin{aligned}
& u(x, y, z)=\sigma \int_{-A}^A d x^{\prime} \int_{-A}^A d y^{\prime} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(x-x^{\prime}\right)^2+\left(y-y^{\prime}\right)^2+z^2}} \\
& P=(0,0, z)   
\end{aligned}
as ${A \rightarrow  \infty}$
where P is the point where I have to evaluate my function

\begin{aligned}
& \rightarrow u(0,0, z)=\sigma \int_{-A}^A d x^{\prime} \int_{-A}^A dy^{\prime} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(x^{\prime}\right)^2+\left(y^{\prime}\right)^2+z^2}}. \\
& \rightarrow dxd y=\rho d \rho d \theta \\
& \rho<\sqrt{2} A \\
& \theta \in[0,2 \pi] \\
& \sqrt{2} A \\
& \Rightarrow u(0,0, z)=\sigma \cdot 2 \cdot \pi \int_0 \frac{\rho d \rho}{\sqrt{\rho^2+z^2}}=2 \pi \cdot \sigma \sqrt{ z^2+2A^2}-|z| \\
& =2 \sqrt{2} \pi \sigma A\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{z}{2A^2} }-\frac{|z|}{A}\right) \\
& \underset{A \rightarrow  \infty}{\rightarrow} 2 \sqrt{2} \pi \sigma A\left(1+\frac{ z^2}{4 A^2}-\frac{|z|}{A}\right) \\
& =2 \sqrt{2} \pi \sigma A-2 \sqrt{2} \pi \sigma z+o\left(\frac{1}{A}\right) \\
& \neq 4\sigma A-2\pi\sigma|z|+o\left(\frac{1}{A}\right) \\
&
\end{aligned}
no one can help me?

Comment: A rectangular domain in Cartesian coordinates will not be a rectangular domain in polar coordinates

Comment: @NinadMunshi hi thanks for answering . How should I fix the integral?

Comment: Draw a picture of the domain if you still want to convert to polar coordinates and figure out what the proper boundaries should be for the integrals. Without symmetry this breaks into 4 integrals

Comment: @NinadMunshi thanks for your help . I have broke integral in 4 parts but I think they are very complicated. the first one is $ \int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \int_0^{A \sec (\theta)} \frac{\rho d \rho\theta d \theta}{\sqrt{\rho^2+z^2}}$   i Can solve the first integral in $\rho$ but the second one looks terrible